# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'IdentityServer.Core.Infrastructure.Notifications.INotificationsService'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'IdentityServer.Admin.Web.Controllers.HomeController'.

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly INotificationsService _notificationsService;
        private readonly ISettingsService _settingsService;

        public HomeController(INotificationsService notificationsService, ISettingsService settingsService)
        {
            _notificationsService = notificationsService;
            _settingsService = settingsService;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
        }

        public PartialViewResult Alerts()
        {
            return PartialView(new AlertsViewModel(_notificationsService.Active()));
        }
    }
```

My Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        }
```

And this is the INotificationsService:

```
 public interface INotificationsService
  {
    void Add(NotificationItem item);
    void Remove(Guid id);
    void Cleanup();

    IEnumerable<NotificationItem> All { get; }
  }

  public static class NotificationsServiceExtensions
  {
    public static void Add(this INotificationsService parent, Guid id, NotificationType type, string title, 
      string message, IEnumerable<NotificationLink> links, DateTime expiration)
    {
      parent.Add(new NotificationItem(id, type, title, message, links, expiration));
    }

    public static void Add(this INotificationsService parent, NotificationType type, string title,
      string message, string linkTitle, string link)
    {
      parent.Add(new NotificationItem(Guid.NewGuid(), type, title, message, new List<NotificationLink>() { new NotificationLink(linkTitle, link)}, 
        DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)));
    }

    public static void Add(this INotificationsService parent, NotificationType type, string title, string message)
    {
      parent.Add(new NotificationItem(Guid.NewGuid(), type, title, message, new List<NotificationLink>(), DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<NotificationItem> Active (this INotificationsService parent)
    {
      return parent.All.Where(x => x.Expiration > DateTime.Now);
    }
  }
```

I know I'm suppose to add it somehow to the startup.cs, but I really don't understand this yet, I'm new to MVC and ASP.NET Core.

Comment: See [Introduction to Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Comment: Thanks, I'm still clueless though. I can't make sense of the interface I already have. (I updated my question including the INotificationsService)

Comment: Well, you don't _have_ to use DI, you can just create instances of the services in your constructor rather than passing them as parameters.

Comment: How though? (Like I said, I'm new to this)

Comment: Like you would create any other object - `_notificationsService = new NotificationsService();`